# Is SQL Server XPath implementation SAX based or DOM based

Tags: sql-server-2008, xml-parsing

A newbie question:

Say, I have a T-SQL like this:

```
     DECLARE @xml XML
         SET @xml = '<r><b>123</b></r><r><b>456</b></r>'
      SELECT row.col.value('(b/text())[1]', 'integer') AS b_id
        FROM @xml.nodes('//r') row(col)
```

When running XPath expression, do we know whether MS Sql Server uses a SAX based parser or a DOM based one? Wanted to get clarification on this as we were thinking of using this to stage a lot of data into a temp table and do further processing on the temp table. In the interest of being polite to the data server (in terms of consuming CPU cycles), we wanted to make sure that we will not cause problems. I tried searching on the net, but couldn't get a definite answer.

Also, should we use OPENXML and does it have any benefits over an adhoc one?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer your SAX/DOM query, but it appears that your real question is how to load XML into SQL Server efficiently. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868647/how-to-load-huge-but-simple-hierarchical-xml-file-into-an-sql-table) mentions one way, and the SQL Server documentation has [others](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191184%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

`OPENXML()` is probably not the best approach because you first have to pass the entire XML document to [sp_xml_preparedocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187367.aspx) as a parameter, which implies that it is not a useful method for bulk loading data.

However, it would probably be best and easiest for you to just start testing and see how different bulk loading solutions perform in your environment.